# Make windows 8 display the "How do you want to open" dialog?

Tags: windows, windows-8, file-association

For example, when you open Chrome, if it is not the default browser you can press a button that will show Windows' dialog prompting you to choose how you want to open http links. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this:

```
C:\windows\system32\openwith.exe "procotol://or/file/to/choose/handler"
```

Answer (score -1):

**You simply right click on the file you want to open**, and you should get the option *Open with* if you hover over it you should get some option of applications that you can open the file with. If you do not like any of the applications it listed, click on *Choose default program...* and you will get a more populated list, and the application you choose will be set as your default application for opening that kind of file.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/b3ef/eijs0xm3iaj6h39fg.jpg))</sub>

Comment: This is stack overflow, not Yahoo Answers, so I thought it would be obvious I'm looking for a way to do it programatically...

Comment: Well excuse me, your question was so short and you provided no information of what you have found so far so I thought you needed to know how to open a file.